# simplepie Apple discussions feed not

Tags: rss, simplepie

I'm just starting to play around with SimplePie, and have created a basic test page that will display the results of an RSS feed on a webpage. This works well when testing a handful of pages, but fails silently when trying to view an Apple Forum feed.

https://discussions.apple.com//community/feeds/search?q=mathtype&peopleEnabled=true&dateRange=all&rankBy=date

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue?

```
<?php
    require_once('php/autoloader.php');
    $feed = new SimplePie();
    $feed->set_feed_url(
        'https://discussions.apple.com//community/feeds/search?q=mathtype&peopleEnabled=true&dateRange=all&rankBy=date'
    );
    $feed->force_feed(true);
    $feed->init();
    $feed->handle_content_type();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample SimplePie Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $feed->get_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php echo $feed->get_description(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
?>
    <div class="item">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
        <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post your PHP & SimplePie code?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself... I checked the return value of `$feed->init()` and it was `false`, so I took out the extra / before "community" in your url and it seems to work.

```
https://discussions.apple.com/community/feeds/search?q=mathtype&peopleEnabled=true&dateRange=all&rankBy=date
```

When you use the double / in your browser, it ignores it, but SimplePie does not.

Comment: Does that seem like something SimplePie's sanitation function should clean up? Wondering if a RegEx to remove any double / should be added...

Comment: Ya, a RegEx to check for that prior to putting in your feeds array would be a good idea.